# Linux: limits.conf values are not honored

Tags: linux, ulimit

I set some values in `/etc/security/limits.conf` as below:

```
*   hard    stack   204800
*   hard    nofile  8192
```

Then rebooted the server. Also I have removed the file `/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf`

However, the `ulimit` command still lists some old/default values:

```
# ulimit -s
10240
# ulimit -n
1024
```

I running `RHEL 6.2 64-bit`

What is wrong here? Is my syntax in `limits.conf` wrong? Why after server reboot it does not honor `limits.conf` values?

BTW, I had posted this question earlier on superuser but failed to get the hits, so trying my luck on serverfault.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are changing hard limit values and querying soft limit values. Everything is working fine. Use `ulimit -H` to view hard limits.

Answer (score 1):

limmits are loaded upon logon. change

> /etc/security/limits.conf

...... logout and log back in.

Comment: I had rebooted the server. still the old/default values.

Comment: more details please... *   hard    stack   204800
*   hard    nofile  8192  <=== not right

Comment: try upping allowed number of processes... nproc

Comment: @alayedbylucifer, adn you def logged out of x,... logged back in right?   ... strange

Comment: TRied `nproc` increase. Still the same old values. In fact `nproc` also lists old value. This ulimit thing is bugging me since last 24 hours and my 10 years of Linux administration experience has gone in the abyss trying to make this work. For whatever reason, NO matter what I put in limits.conf, nothing is honored and it pulls some default values which I do not know where it is coming from.

Comment: well, you can test by fork bomb on a restricted via ulimits account..... try:  :(){ :|:& };:

Comment: nproc limits number of porcesesses

Comment: tried it the fokrbomb as well, but I immediately loose connection to my EC2 instance and then I have reboot it to get it back. The real question is, where `ulimit` command is pulling values from?